# How to use a angular variable as a parameter in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use an angular variable as a JavaScript parameters like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="link in Links">
    <button data-icon="gear" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" type="button" id="bitrate_btn_{{ link.Code }}" class="bitrate_btn btn" onClick="play_live_ind({{link.Code}});">
        {{ link.Title }} ( {{ link.Bitrate }} Kbps )
    </button>
 </li>
```

As you can see I'm calling a method called `play_live_ind` like this:

```
play_live_ind({{link.Code}});
```

It's not working, as the page loads it exactly prints 
`play_live_ind({{link.Code}});`

How can I pass the value of link to this **JavaScript function**?

This is a jw-player function that I can't rewrite it in angular because it has many function call on itself. So I need to call this function in **javascript**

So I just need a solution to pass the angular variable value to the **Javascript** function

Comment: Use `ng-click` instead of `onClick`.

Comment: This function is a javascript  function, I used it with ng-click but because it's not a angular fucntion, it won't run, how can I run it then?

Comment: define `play_live_ind` as `$scope.play_live_ind = function(inputs) { // function body}`

Comment: This is not my function, this is jw-player functions so I can't rewrite them in angular, it has many dependencies, so I need a solution to pass the angular value to the javascript function

Comment: And also, `onClick` should be changed to - `onclick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click` instead of `onClick`, and define `play_live_ind` in your `$scope`.

```
//html
ng-click="play_live_ind(link.Code)";

//js
$scope.play_live_ind = function(inputs) { 
                          // function body 
                       }
```